# AwesomeWM, get an array of all the managed clients

Tags: lua, lua-table, awesome-wm

Is it possible (and how) to get an array of all the managed clients in awesomeWM?

I currently do it using the `managed` signal, adding the client to an array that I can acess later. But I'm only half satissfied with that solution. 
Indeed, I don't know any efficient way to use the `client` object passed as argument by the signal `unmanage` to remove it from my array.
Therefore my array contains the killed clients too. That's not handy.

Finally, is there a built-in function or another way to get that array?

My version is: awesome v3.4.15 (Never Gonna Give You Up)

Comment: What is the argument type to the managed signal? Is your removal issue that you have an array? Would a hash work for your usage? That would allow simple removal. If not you could always dual-use the array and store the array index as the value for the client in the hash-part of the table (i.e. `ind=5; arr[ind] = client; arr[client] = ind`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `client.get()` gives you a table containing all managed clients and `client.get(1)` gives you all clients on screen 1.

http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/client.html#get